# Blocking request failed HttpServerExchange on GET request over GWT and websocket and wildfly

Tags: gwt, jboss, websocket

When trying to implement **HTML5 websocket** over **Jboss Wildfly 8**, an error message shows that **"Blocking request failed HttpServerExchange"** and it doesn't connect! 
The problem is to create a new instance of **ServerEndpoint** of your websocket servlet as it says clearly at the first line of stack trace message. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!
The problem was in **web.xml**. 
The **servlet class** needs to be specified in web.xml.